# separar números por múltiplos python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Me han dado un trabajo en el cual debo hacer el siguiente procedimiento de un contexto:
Una empanada de queso tiene el valor de `250`, tres empanadas de queso serán `600` (por una promoción) y cinco empanadas de queso serán `750`.
Entonces en base a esto por 14 empanadas se pagaría: `2x750+1x600+1x250= 2350`
Mi problema es que si bien logro sacar los resultados de multiplos de `3` y `5` con sus respectivas promociones al poner un número como `14` no entra en este caso, y no funciona por ende necesito separar este numero en: dos de `5`, uno de `3` y uno de `1`, pero no logro hacerlo, alguien puede ayudarme a plantear este problema?

**Código**

```
def empanaditas():
    solicitarempanada=int(input("Cuantas empanaditas va a ordenar: "))
    seguir= True
    while (seguir):
        if solicitarempanada<=2:
            empanada1=250
            solicitarempanada=(solicitarempanada*empanada1)
            seguir= False       
        elif solicitarempanada%3==0:
            empanada2=200
            solicitarempanada=(solicitarempanada*empanada2)
            seguir= False
        elif solicitarempanada%5==0:
            empanada3=150
            solicitarempanada=(solicitarempanada*empanada3)
            seguir= False
        elif solicitarempanada
        else:
            solicitarempanada=int(input("La cantidad no es valida, vuelva a ordenar: "))
    return solicitarempanada
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dices algo así:

```
def empanaditas(numeroDeEmpanadas):
    precioFinal=0
    empanadas=numeroDeEmpanadas
    while(empanadas>0):
        if empanadas>=5:
            precioDeEmpanada = 150
            PromosDe5empanadas = int(empanadas/5)
            precioFinal += PromosDe5empanadas * 5 * precioDeEmpanada
            empanadas -= PromosDe5empanadas*5

        elif empanadas>=3:
            precioDeEmpanada = 200
            PromosDe3empanadas = int(empanadas/3)
            precioFinal += PromosDe3empanadas * 3 * precioDeEmpanada
            empanadas -= PromosDe3empanadas*3    
        else:
            precioDeEmpanada = 250
            precioFinal += empanadas * precioDeEmpanada
            empanadas=0
    return precioFinal 


solicitarEmpanada=int(input("Cuantas empanaditas va a ordenar: "))
print empanaditas(solicitarEmpanada);
```

Primero que nada, el número de empanadas es mejor colocarlo como parámetro y luego ir aumentando el costo de la compra a medida que las empanadas se vendan.

Como veras, el caso que va primero es cuando es posible comprar 5 empanadas a la vez, si no es posible, salta el siguiente caso (reduciendo la cantidad de empanadas).

Si te preguntas para que puse **int(empanadas/5)** fue para ver la cantidad de grupos enteros de 5 elementos, por ej: **17** -> **17/5 = 3.4** y su parte entera es **3**.

Es posible hacer el mismo proceso mediante recursión, pero si lo muestras así estaría bien, si quieres investígalo.

Unos consejos que te voy a dar:

- Si vas a usar un bucle while, la forma correcta de salir de este es
  mediante la palabra reservada **break**.
- Sólo por convención el nombre de las variables comienzan en
  minúsculas y las siguientes palabras en mayúsculas, ej: **holaComoEstas**.
- No crees distintas variables para guardar cantidades de un mismo
  tipo, ya que puedes redefinir su valor (mira precioDeEmpanada).
- Si quieres, ya sea: sumar, restar, multiplicar, una cantidad a una
  variable, es más cómodo usar los operadores += , -= , *= , /= , se
  cacha mejor con un ejemplo: **hola += 1** en vez de **hola = hola +
  1** u **hola /= 2** en vez de **hola = hola/2**

Pucha que son wenas las empanadas.
Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez lo que te está faltando es que solo estás considerando valores múltiplos de 5 y 3, además de valores, menores iguales que 2. Siguiendo un poco con tu idea, te propongo la siguiente solución:

```
def empanaditas():
    # Cantidad de empanadas a comprar
    solicitarempanada = int(input("Cuantas empanaditas va a ordenar: "))
    # Total a pagar
    total = 0

    if solicitarempanada >= 5:
        # Se obtiene la cantidad de empanadas para la promocion de 5
        # Por ejemplo si son 14, se obtendria 2
        cantidad = solicitarempanada // 5
        # Restar la cantidad de empanadas
        # En el ejemplo que pusiste serian 10
        # Por lo tanto en la variable queda 4
        solicitarempanada = solicitarempanada - 5 * cantidad
        # Se cobra el precio
        # En este caso se agregaria 2*750
        total = total + cantidad * 750

    if solicitarempanada >= 3:
        # Se obtiene la cantidad de empanadas para la promocio de 3
        # Como quedan 4, se obtendria 3
        cantidad = solicitarempanada // 3
        # Restar la cantidad de empanadas
        # Como quedan 4, la variable ahora seria 1
        solicitarempanada = solicitarempanada - 3 * cantidad
        # Se cobra el precio
        # En este caso se agregaria 1*600
        total = total + cantidad * 600

    if solicitarempanada >= 1:
        # Se cobra el precio de las empanadas restantes
        # En este caso se agregaria 1*250
        total = total + solicitarempanada*250

    return total
```

Creo que eso se asemeja más a la solución buscada según como lo pensaste. En fin hay otras formas de hacerlo que tal vez resulten un poco más eficiente.

Otra forma de sumarle un valor a una variable sería:

```
total = total + cantidad # Esto
total += cantidad # es equivalente a esto
```

Lo mismo sucede con la resta, la multiplicación, la división y otras operaciones.

Espero que te haya quedado claro y haya podido satisfacer tu duda.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Supongamos que nos piden `numero_empanadas`. Para saber cuántas promociones de 5 empanadas se conseguirían basta hacer una división:

```
promo5 = numero_empanadas / 5
resto = numero_empanadas % 5
```

Con el `resto`, bastaría con saber si es suficiente para la promoción de las 3 empanadas y calcular el precio total en consecuencia.

Aprovechando que tenemos la función `divmod` que hace las dos operaciones, división y módulo, podemos componer una función de la manera más sencilla:

```
PRECIO = 300
PROMO3 = 600
PROMO5 = 750

def empanaditas(numero_empanadas):
    (promo5, resto) = divmod(numero_empanadas, 5)
    (promo3, num) = divmod(resto, 3)
    return promo5 * PROMO5 + promo3 * PROMO3 + num
```